# javascript save function usage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning about building a new user login app and there is a line of code the makes me quite confused and Google did not show me any enlightening result.

```js
module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
 bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
     bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
         newUser.password = hash;
         newUser.save(callback);
     });
 });
}
```

It is quite straightforward: The new user module is trying to crypt the password and runs the callback(It is my understanding). But this line here:

```js
newUser.save(callback);
```

It is very confusing to me and would anyone explain what it does here?
Thank you

Comment: `newUser.save(callback);` executes the `save` function of the `newUser` module. When the async operation is done and the result is ready. The `callback` param of `createUser = function(newUser, callback)` will be called

Comment: `callback` would mean you have to pass a function that gets executed after `save` is complete. JavaScript is async. You have to handle async events like this.

Comment: `JavaScript is async`. This is absolutely wrong. Node is async not JS

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript

Comment: @CodeLover so you are saying Node is not JS?

Comment: Yes, it is not. Node is an asynchronous IO runtime and JS is a programming language. The relationship is Node modules and apps are written in JS.

Comment: Yeah, JS is async. https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/synchronous-asynchronous-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose save method expects an optional callback function as an argument ([Reference Doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)). So when you are calling `newUser.save(callback);` you are passing the same callback function that you got in the `createUser(newUser, callback);` so whichever method will call this method i.e. suppose in following code callIt() function is calling your code.

```
module.exports.createUser = (newUser, callback) => {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
};

function callIt() {
    module.exports.createUser({ name: 'ridham' }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(user);
        }
    });
}    

callIt();
```

so here you are giving `function (err, user) {...}` function as an argument which can be called by invoked function to pass back the access to invoking the function(handling async nature of JS). and your invoke function again invoking another function passing the same callback reference so basically, you are chaining the same callback.

Callback Explanations can be found [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) and [here](http://callbackhell.com/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that .save() is a mongoose function. I just read the reference and looks like this method will save `newUser` to mongodb database?

Comment: Yeah right and you are passing same callback that you got to mongoose function so after saving user into db mongoose will call your call back function that you have passed at createUser. If your doubts are clear than mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a callback function as a parameter to the outer most function. And when the genSalt- and hash-functions are done, you pass the same callback function as a parameter to `newUser.save()`. It is a function that (probably) will be executed inside `newUser.save()`.

Sometimes using callbacks are a way to say that some code has completed, and then run a new function. Useful for async funcions.

A simpler example:

```
serveCake = function(){ // this is my callback function
 // serve the cake
}

createCake = function(ingredients, callback){ // pass serveCake as a callback here.
 // Mix the ingredients and put the cake in the oven
 // When the cake is finished baking, serve it
 callback(); // call the callback function.
}
const ingredients = ['suger', 'butter'];

createCake(ingredients,serveCake);
```

The same happens with your code, but the callback function will (probably) be executed inside the `newUser.save()`-method.

Comment: Thanks John. I can understand the callback function part. But I just don't get what .save function here is doing. Because like you said, this code snippet would execute the callback content after hashed the password, so what does it exactly trying to 'save' here?

Comment: the callback will be executed not after the password has been hashed, but (most likely) after the logic inside the .save()-function has completed. I do not know the content inside the save()-function, but I am guessing that they are saving the user in the database with the updated hashed password. Simply calling `newUser.password = hash` would only temporary save the password. Calling .save() will then store that data. This is only speculation, and I am not aware of the contents inside the save()-function.